# implementing a delay function in assembly code

Tags: assembly, delay, pic, mplab

I've been trying to get the K_100MS subroutine to work on a simple led light up program for the PIC16F84 microcontroller. The following code builds fine, but the delay does not implement when simulating it in Proteus ISIS. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
list      p=16f84         ; list directive to define processor
#include <p16F84.inc>        ; processor specific variable definitions
errorlevel  -302 , -207             ; suppress message 302 from list file

__config _XT_OSC & _CP_OFF & _PWRTE_OFF & _WDT_OFF


ORG     0x00            ; processor reset vector
goto    start              ; go to beginning of program


COUNT_H equ 30h ; 2-byte counter
COUNT_L equ 31h ; at File 20:1h
K equ 32h ; Temporary storage for K
N equ d'130'  
DELAY_K100MS
movwf K ; Put K away in a register file
; Task 1: DO 100ms delay
movlw N ; Set up high count to 130
movwf COUNT_H
clrf COUNT_L ; and low count to 256
DK_LOOP
decfsz COUNT_L,f ; Decrement LS count to zero
goto DK_LOOP ; taking in all H*[(256*3)-1]˜
decfsz COUNT_H,f ; Repeat for the MS byte
goto DK_LOOP ; taking in all (H*3)-1˜
; Task 2: Decrement K
decfsz K,f
; Task 3: WHILE K > 0
goto DK_LOOP ; REPEAT WHILE K > 0
FINI return




PORTB                        EQU     H'0006'
TRISB                        EQU     H'0086'
STATUS                       EQU     H'0003'
RP0                          EQU     H'0005'


start:
bsf STATUS, RP0
clrf TRISB
bcf STATUS, RP0
movlw   b'01111110'
movwf PORTB
movlw d'10' ; 10 x 0.1s gives one second
call DELAY_K100MS 
clrf PORTB
end
```